# How to remove the gap around large icon in notification

Tags: android, notifications

There's always a gap around large icon in the notification. [image]

How to remove the gap?
And I don't wanna customize notification, just use original notification.
Help.

ps:
the pic is from a 1280*720(xhdpi) device. and that view in my device is 120*120. and I use a same size icon here.

Comment: it's default padding you need to use larger icons for notification

Comment: @VINILSATRASALA In my device, that view size is 120*120. And I use the same size icon, now we can see that gap.

Comment: For different resolutions we have to use different size icons or else you can use 172*172 in XXHDPI, it will manage all the resolutions as of I know

Comment: Use 172*172 for XXHDPI, 144*144 for XHDPI, 124*124 for HDPI

Comment: @VINILSATRASALA Thanks. I will try 144*144 on my device. But I think it won't work, because that view is 120*120.

Comment: @VINILSATRASALA It works... But 144*144 is too large. Which size is right?

Comment: in which folder are you placing it?

Comment: @VINILSATRASALA drawable-xhdpi

Comment: I would suggest with going 172*172 in xxhdpi

Comment: @VINILSATRASALA The gap is still there. I think I have to customize the notification now. Thanks.